# Is it possible to animate massive time seise data using Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, time-series, chart.js

I have massive time series data like this

```
   .
   .
   .
{"Time": "18:47:49", "Temperature": "23.27"},
{"Time": "18:52:50", "Temperature": "23.27"},
{"Time": "18:57:49", "Temperature": "23.27"},
{"Time": "19:02:50", "Temperature": "23.27"},
{"Time": "19:07:49", "Temperature": "23.27"},
   .
   .
   .
```

I want animate line chart like a realtime streaming chart.

1. Update both ends of X axis sequentially and load data and redraw?
   It's not efficient. Become a jerky animation
2. I had try to use [chartjs-plugin-streaming](https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-streaming/).
   It seems so good. But only the current time will be assigned on the X axis.

```
dataset.data.push({
    x: Date.now(),
    y: Math.random()
});
```

I want to animate the graph by sequentially updating the time of the data file

3. Or, Or, preload all the data in advance, and sequentially change the time at both ends of the X axis of the chart according to the specified time width.
   Then update (); is called sequentially, but isn't it smooth animation?

I want to achieve smooth animation even with large data with a simple implementation.

Comment: What does "massive" mean? 1,000 data points? 100,000? And how many really need to be displayed at any one time?

Comment: 36,288points. 18charts in a window  and 7lines in a chart.

Comment: And how many data points (per series) need to be visible at any one time? What's the update frequency? Every series on every chart every X seconds?

Comment: Max 288 points per series( lines). Actually it zooms, so the number of points is smaller. I want to update over 10fps.

Comment: At 10 fps I'd reduce the number of points per line to around 20 or so. If you need to show general trend I'd average every 10 points. If you need to detect spikes I'd take the max value of each 10 point range.

Comment: If so, I need to change the data size dynamically.